# Lack of ImageList in MenuStrip and performance issues

Tags: c#, imagelist

MenuStrip doesn't support using ImageList images.

What are performance issues of this? Are there chances of using too much GDI resources and slow-downs? How many items should be considered acceptable, after which one should implement custom control that draws images from ImageList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MenuStrip` is a subclass of `ToolStrip`, which has an [`ImageList` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.imagelist.aspx)... what makes you think it isn't supported ?

Comment: Funny thing, I searched over the Net and found information that it is not supported I think even somewhere on this site...

Yes, I see now that it is supported as allonym said, but not from designer...